# Rails Turbolinks renders partial in head each time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks

If I understand right Turbolinks keeps you from reloading the same javascript\css assets more than once, however I have a navigation bar that I render as a partial , and I want it to only be rendered once - on initial load and for lifetime of my app. I thought putting it in the head tag instead of body would help since turbolinks replaces your entire body , but it seems my entire application.html.erb is being rendered each time I click on a turbolink , and while the assets are somehow only loaded once all the rest is re-rendered . This might be the expected behavior but I just want to know if there's a solution.
Is there any way to only render once ?

```
application.html.erb

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="he" dir="rtl">
<head>
<%=render partial: 'layouts/navigation'%>  //I want to render only once for the life time of my app
```

Comment: What I'm asking is , do I have to render the navigation bar on client side or just forget the whole thing?

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be some misconceptions here:

- Turbolink speeds up loading of Javascript and CSS, because these are only loaded once. That is not true for the HTML part (wich is constructed by your call to `render partial: ...`).
- Rendering in the `head` section of HTML does not make sense at all. The head is for declaring things, rendering happens only in the `body` section.

Perhaps you should just render it in the body, and forget about the speed thing, unless you have a problem with it.